Cut crawl space vapor barrier?
I am in the process of adding a dehumidifier into my crawl space following the encapsulation. The previous owner have vapor barrier installed without a dehumidifier. The crawl space floor is not leveled. My proposed solution is to create two 8x16-inch holes to level the ground, then tape the cutting back to it's original state. Alternatively, would it be better to hang the dehumidifier instead?

Why not create a level base and put it on the vapor barrier?

Could you elaborate on the materials suitable for creating a level base? I've considered using sand above the vapor barrier to level it. However, I'm uncertain about how to effectively contain the sand in place. Any suggestions?

A pressure treated lumber base made to sit in the spot was what I was thinking, but a poured concrete base could work too depending on how much room you have. You can add rubber isolation feet to the base to minimize any vibrations from the compressor. Vibrations are the reason I would not hang from the floor. Cutting the vapor barrier is a good option as well but it is important to really seal it properly after.
